# Regionprops (skimage.measure) for Video in Python

Tags: python-3.x, video-processing, label, region

I got a piece of code on internet that '[Label image regions](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html)' and tried to run it over a video , but all I get is first frame and than an error after closing the first frame window " max() arg is an empty sequence" from line" `plt.tight_layout()` of my code. I am trying to get label for all the frames in my video instead of single image example as shown in the given example above (link). Basically the code should display/plot all the frames with labels.

Any help will be really useful.Please find my code below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
from skimage.morphology import closing, square
from skimage.color import label2rgb


cap =  cv2.VideoCapture('test3.mp4')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

while(1):
    t = time.time()
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
    bw = closing(image > thresh, square(3))

    # remove artifacts connected to image border
    cleared = clear_border(bw)

    # label image regions
    label_image = label(cleared)
    image_label_overlay = label2rgb(label_image, image=frame2)
    x = regionprops(label_image)
    area2 = [r.area for r in x]
    print(area2)
    ax.imshow(image_label_overlay)

    for region in regionprops(label_image):
        # take regions with large enough areas
        if region.area >= 100:
           # draw rectangle around segmented coins
            minr, minc, maxr, maxc = region.bbox
            rect = mpatches.Rectangle((minc, minr), maxc - minc, maxr -minr,
                                   fill=False, edgecolor='red', linewidth=2)
            ax.add_patch(rect)

    ax.set_axis_off()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
 cap.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wola!

And the solution is:

1.) Error rectification: **"max() arg is an empty sequence"** from line   **`plt.tight_layout()`** can be removed using  **`fig.tight_layout`** rather than **`plt.tight_layout`**. Because after I was closing the first frame of video (that was not updating, well that's another problem I am still pondering on!!) the figure was empty and it was raising an exception as **`tight.layout`** trying to run on an empty figure.

2.) Running [Label image regions](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html) code for video is made possible if you replace line

```
    rect = mpatches.Rectangle((minc, minr), maxc - minc+50, maxr - minr+50,fill=False, edgecolor='red', linewidth=2)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.set_axis_off()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

with

```
   cv2.rectangle(frame2, (minc, minr), (minc +maxc - minc , minr + maxr - minr), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('ObjectTrack', frame2) # this line outside the if loop
```

Basically display the video the way it is in simple [Capture Video from Camera](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) program of Python.